# How can I create a drop down menu with google app engine?

Tags: html, css, menu, drop-down-menu

I trying to make a drop down menu with Google app engine and 
http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex1/droptabmenu.htm

I follow above instruction from above website, it seems css file is not working
with google app engine ??

Does anyone know how to make drop down menu with google app engine or 
how can I use css with google app engine?

Comment: It is nothing to do with GAE. Check your code.. Are you using java or python?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure your app for serving static files.

Docs:

- [python](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html)
- [java](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can you [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to detect 404 not found css or javascript files.

code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles.html